# Error occured when downloading wubi 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wubi

I tried to download Ubuntu 12.04, but it froze so i shut down the computer. I tried again and a window popped up saying:
An error occurred:
Cannot  install into c:\ubuntu
There is another file or directory with this name
Please remove it before continuing
For more information, please see the log file

Log file has the following contents:

```
12-20 20:11 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain H:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:11 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether H:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-20 20:11 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain H:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:11 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether H:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-20 20:11 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain H:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:11 INFO   root: Running the installer...
12-20 20:11 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: __init__...
12-20 20:11 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: on_init...
12-20 20:11 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8002.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
12-20 20:11 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8002.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
12-20 20:12 DEBUG  WinuiInstallationPage: target_drive=C:, installation_size=18000MB, distro_name=Ubuntu, language=en_US, locale=en_US.UTF-8, username=peter
12-20 20:12 INFO   root: Received settings
12-20 20:12 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local CD
12-20 20:12 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8002.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:12 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8002.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:12 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:12 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:12 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:12 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:12 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:12 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:12 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether G:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:12 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain G:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:12 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether H:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:12 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain H:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:12 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local ISO
12-20 20:12 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl8002.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
12-20 20:12 DEBUG  TaskList: # Running tasklist...
12-20 20:12 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running select_target_dir...
12-20 20:12 ERROR  TaskList: Cannot install into C:\ubuntu.
There is another file or directory with this name.
Please remove it before continuing.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 81, in select_target_dir
Exception: Cannot install into C:\ubuntu.
There is another file or directory with this name.
Please remove it before continuing.
12-20 20:12 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
12-20 20:12 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
12-20 20:12 ERROR  root: Cannot install into C:\ubuntu.
There is another file or directory with this name.
Please remove it before continuing.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 81, in select_target_dir
Exception: Cannot install into C:\ubuntu.
There is another file or directory with this name.
Please remove it before continuing.
12-20 20:20 INFO   root: === wubi 12.04 rev269 ===
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  root: Logfile is c:\users\peter\appdata\local\temp\wubi-12.04-rev269.log
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  root: sys.argv = ['main.pyo', '--exefile="C:\\Users\\PETER\\Desktop\\Wubi\\wubi.exe"']
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend: data_dir=C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp\data
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: 7z=C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp\bin\7z.exe
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: startup_folder=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Fetching basic info...
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend: original_exe=C:\Users\PETER\Desktop\Wubi\wubi.exe
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend: platform=win32
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend: osname=nt
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend: language=en_US
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend: encoding=cp1252
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: arch=amd64
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Parsing isolist=C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp\data\isolist.ini
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Xubuntu-i386
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-i386
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Xubuntu-amd64
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-amd64
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-i386
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-amd64
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-amd64
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-i386
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-i386
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-amd64
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-i386
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-amd64
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Fetching host info...
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: registry_key=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows version=vista
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_version2=Windows 7 Ultimate
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_sp=None
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_build=7601
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: gmt=-5
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: country=US
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: timezone=America/New_York
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_username=PETER
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_full_name=PETER
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_directory=C:\Users\PETER
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language_code=1033
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language=English
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: processor_name=AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 6000+
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: bootloader=vista
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: system_drive=Drive(C: hd 894380.753906 mb free ntfs)
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(C: hd 894380.753906 mb free ntfs)
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(D: cd 0.0 mb free cdfs)
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(E: removable 0.0 mb free )
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(F: removable 0.0 mb free )
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(G: removable 0.0 mb free )
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(H: removable 0.0 mb free )
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: uninstaller_path=None
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_target_dir=None
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_distro_name=None
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_id=67699721
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_layout=us
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_variant=
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend: python locale=('en_US', 'cp1252')
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend: locale=en_US.UTF-8
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: total_memory_mb=4095.99999905
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching ISOs on USB devices
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local CDs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp is a valid Xubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp is a valid Xubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Xubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Xubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Xubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Xubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Xubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Xubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether G:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain G:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether G:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain G:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether G:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain G:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether G:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain G:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether G:\ is a valid Xubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain G:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether G:\ is a valid Xubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain G:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether G:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain G:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether G:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain G:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether G:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain G:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether G:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain G:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether G:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain G:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether G:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain G:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether H:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain H:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether H:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain H:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether H:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain H:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether H:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain H:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether H:\ is a valid Xubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain H:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether H:\ is a valid Xubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain H:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether H:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain H:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether H:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain H:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether H:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain H:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether H:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain H:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether H:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain H:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether H:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain H:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 INFO   root: Running the installer...
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: __init__...
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: on_init...
12-20 20:20 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
12-20 20:20 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  WinuiInstallationPage: target_drive=C:, installation_size=18000MB, distro_name=Ubuntu, language=en_US, locale=en_US.UTF-8, username=peter
12-20 20:20 INFO   root: Received settings
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether G:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain G:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether H:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain H:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local ISO
12-20 20:20 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7C79.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  TaskList: # Running tasklist...
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running select_target_dir...
12-20 20:20 ERROR  TaskList: Cannot install into C:\ubuntu.
There is another file or directory with this name.
Please remove it before continuing.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 81, in select_target_dir
Exception: Cannot install into C:\ubuntu.
There is another file or directory with this name.
Please remove it before continuing.
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
12-20 20:20 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
12-20 20:20 ERROR  root: Cannot install into C:\ubuntu.
There is another file or directory with this name.
Please remove it before continuing.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 81, in select_target_dir
Exception: Cannot install into C:\ubuntu.
There is another file or directory with this name.
Please remove it before continuing.
```

PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: Have to installed Ubuntu before?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the first run made a folder called `C:\ubuntu`, so the second time round it's not gunna overwrite `C:\ubuntu`. Try deleting `C:\ubuntu` or just renaming it to something else (like `C:\ubuntu-tmp`) and running wubi again